# powershell: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

Tags: powershell, ssh, openssh

This is only failing on Powershell and PSCore  > Windows/Linux connections
Same keys work for Linux > Windows/Linux connections

We also have same keys on a mirrored DR site that works no problem.
Permissions of all keys Prod/DR are the same

PS D:> ssh xxx
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
user@xxx: Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 2):

"ssh-add -d" on each key removed it from cache, which was the problem